# Creating a live connection to airtable from tableau

Tags: python, automation, tableau-api, airtable

Not sure whether this is the correct outlet for this question but here goes. Currently, my company’s connection to airtable has to be refreshed manually when we are updating our dashboards. However, we are looking to speed this up by periodically running the flow so that the dashboard can be updated automatically.

As of now, what I've researched is to use pyairtable to extract the data and clean it within python first and then use a separate automation script (pythonanywhere maybe) to run this extract periodically.

My question is: Is there a better way to go about this, or is this really the fastest way to connect it？

Answer (score 1):

So there's more than one way to do this. Short answer: If you just need something that's fairly basic & user-friendly, use an automation application. If it's gonna be doing a bunch of complex data transformations or if you need to have more control over the finer details of exactly how this integration functions, you'll probably need to go with a custom script.

A. Automation Applications/Software

1. Zapier
2. Integromat

B. Custom Script

1. Choose the programming language you prefer.
   a. Python & JavaScript are both good options.
2. Create a dashboard using that programming language, or connect the script's output to a 3rd-party dashboard service.
3. Write a script to extract data from Airtable & to update your custom dashboard (or update/sync with your chosen 3rd-party dashboard service).
4. Set a task scheduler to periodically run your python script.
   a. This way, you can easily adjust the frequency if needed.

If you use a 3rd-party service, just make sure to compare prices. Some will cost money & others may be free.

If you use a custom script, that's obviously gonna be free. But it could be harder to set it up if you aren't familiar with any of this sort of stuff.

But either way should work. And if you have trouble with one, you can always try out the other way.